# Cardinality of sets, relations, and functions

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory

If there are two sets, A and B with each having finite number of elements, what would be the cardinalities of a set of all relations and a set of all functions from A to B?

1. Relations: Since a relation is a subset of cartesian product, would cardinality of the set of all relations from A to B be the cardinality of the power set of A x B? So if set A has 2 elements, and B has 3 elements, then cardinality of the set of all relations is $2^6$?
2. Functions: Since a function is a relation where each element from the domain has exactly 1 associated element from the co-domain, if cardinality of set A is x and cardinality of set B is y, then cardinality of all functions from A to B is $y^x$?

Comment: That is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your explanation is absolutely correct. For the first one, you could subtract $1$ because people usually define a relation to be a nonempty subset of $A$x$B$. Empty relations are not that good.:p

Comment: Well, I don't and am certainly not the only one in this. I cannot find a good reason for leaving out the empty relation.

Comment: Empty relations in real life are not good. You got a point there.

Comment: Empty relations are not reflexive. Well, you can definitely consider them as relations but they are useless.

Comment: Thanks! One place I found empty relation useful is when modeling ME -> FRIENDS

Comment: You're most welcome.